# Scaling an object up and down in an animation?

Tags: animation, scale

i'm trying to make a very easy animation rotating an object (pretty much a plane) while making it grow and shrink. i know there must be an easy way to do it as i've done something similar before but my brain's done a fart and can't seem to get it right.
at the moment when i try to scale the object down in a keyframe it scales to that size permanently, affecting the size in all other keyframes. does anyone have any helpful tips and tricks? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have moved and rotated your object and only created *Location* and *Rotation* keyframes, without creating any *Scale* keyframe, the animation will take into account the first *Scale* keyframe it meets and the scale of the object won't change until it meets the next *Scale* keyframe. If you want to make sure that the scale is taken into account at frame X you should keyframe with *LocRotScale* (or *LocScale* or *RotScale*).

Comment: Thanks so much!!!